# Postgres/ActiveRecord sorting by letters then numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to sort an ActiveRecord query alphabetically, case-insensitive, but with letters taking precedence over numbers.

So this:

```
[
  93124, my town,
  springfield,
  hooverville,
  10075, upper east side,
  Austin, TX
]
```

becomes:

```
[
  Austin, TX,
  hooverville,
  springfield,
  10075, upper east side,
  93124, my town
]
```

This is really eluding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `substring` method of `postgresql` with a `pattern`.

Assuming you have `Location` model with `name` column. Column `name` having above values. Let's order them.

```
@locations = Location.select("name").order("SUBSTRING(name, '^[A-Za-z].*'), SUBSTRING(name, '^[0-9]+')::INTEGER")
```

This will sort the column `name` first by character then by digits.

```
@locations.map(&:name)

=> ["Austin, TX", "hooverville", "springfield", "10075, upper east side", "93124, my town"]
```

Hope this will be helpful.